# Show Value and Percentage % on Bar Graph

Tags: powerbi

I currently have customer wise Revenue and Net Profit Margin (%).

How can i show a bar graph with the Revenue Figures and display both Revenue Value and respective Net profit margin as data labels?

Need help

Answer (score 0):

The steps that you need to use to create a bar graph by including data labels can be found in this reference [Please refer the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-report-add-visualizations-i)

I hope this will help you to solve the issue.

Comment: Hi, i don't think you understood my question. i know to create a bar graph. how can i show both value and percentage under data labels?

Comment: for that you can refer [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Showing-percentage-and-number-values-in-visuals-at-the-same-time/m-p/51871#M20855)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Put Your measure in tooltip in barchart so it will show you the value in hover.